# Why in the world is this answer green?

Tags: discussion, answers

From [this question on Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/172784/do-all-combinatorially-distinct-fundamental-polygons-correspond-to-surfaces).

[image: wut]

What?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*All* accepted answers on Math Overflow get a green background. It is part of the site design inherited from before the site was merged into the Stack Exchange network.

Also see [Should the accepted answer really have a green background?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1565/should-the-accepted-answer-really-have-a-green-background) on the Math Overflow Meta.

Comment: So is this something the moderators of a beta can do, or what?

Comment: @JeffGohlke: no, it is something the designers did when the site graduated from beta.

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't know they had that kind of customization power.  I figured it was just background themes and icons.

Comment: Because green is the best color... Wait no, blue is!

Comment: @MartijnPieters MO didn't go through the Area 51 process. The old design was simply copied by the SE designer when they joined the network.

Comment: @bluefeet: http://youtu.be/pWS8Mg-JWSg?t=1m21s

Comment: @MadScientist: ah, than explains why I cannot find the design post on MO.